# Can't update the sqlite3 database in python

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3-python

I have been making a python project using tkinter. I am also using SQLite3 database(tables). The project has a function to update the database, but the messagebox throws an exceptional error.I tried to remove the exception code but still the database won't get updated.

the database name is: 'criminal_records'.

```
#update code
    def update_data(self):
        if self.var_case_id.get()=="":
            messagebox.showerror('Error','All fields are required')
        else:
            try:
                update=messagebox.askyesno('Update', "Are you sure you want to update this record?")
                if update>0:
                    conn=sqlite3.connect('criminal_records.db')
                    my_cursor=conn.cursor() 
                    my_cursor.execute('UPDATE criminal_records SET Case ID=?, Criminal Name=?,Case Number=?,Date of crime=?, Crime Type=?, Description=?,Block=?,Location=?,Arrest Date=?, Age=?, Gender=?, WHERE Case Id=?', (
                        self.var_case_id.get(),
                        self.var_name.get(),
                        self.var_case_number.get(),
                        self.var_date_of_crime.get(),
                        self.var_crime_type.get(),
                        self.var_description.get(),
                        self.var_block.get(),
                        self.var_location.get(),
                        self.var_arrest_date.get(),
                        self.var_age.get(),
                        self.var_gender.get(),
                        
                    ))

                else:
                    if not update:
                        return
                conn.commit()
                self.fetch_data()
                self.clear_data()
                conn.close()
                messagebox.showinfo('Successful', 'Criminal record has been updated')
            except Exception as es:
                messagebox.showerror('Error',f'Due to{str(es)}')
```

OUTPUT
[image: This is the output I am getting.]

Comment: If a column name has spaces in it, you have to put it in backticks: ```SET `Case ID` = ?```

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote the column names that contain spaces with backticks.

```
my_cursor.execute('UPDATE criminal_records SET `Case ID`=?, `Criminal Name`=?,`Case Number`=?,`Date of crime`=?, `Crime Type`=?, Description=?,Block=?,Location=?,`Arrest Date`=?, Age=?, Gender=? WHERE `Case Id`=?, (
```

You also have an extra `,` before `WHERE`, and you're missing the value for `` WHERE `Case ID`=? `` in the parameter tuple.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.However, after updating, the message box shows, "Due to incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 12, and there are 11 supplied."My database has 11 columns.

Comment: @AaA But there are 12 placeholders in the SQL statement, the 11 columns to be updated and the one in WHERE clause. Actually you don't need to update the `Case ID` column because it is the search condition.

Comment: @Barmar Alright! Will look into it.

Comment: Didn't you read the last part of answer? I said that you were missing one of the values.

Answer (score 0):

The error message in the screen shot comes from the code `Due to{str(es)}`, meaning that `es` is "near `Case`: syntax error"  There is a syntax error near `Case` because your column is `Case ID`, which includes a space, but that space is not handled in your `UPDATE` statement (and other columns likewise).  You should encapsulate the column in single or double quotes:

```
UPDATE criminal_records SET "Case ID"=?, "Criminal Name"=?,"Case Number"=?,"Date of crime"=?, "Crime Type"=?, Description=?,Block=?,Location=?,"Arrest Date"=?, Age=?, Gender=? WHERE "Case Id"=?
```

Note I have also removed the extra comma before `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

There are issues in your SQL statement:

- need to enclose those *column names* with space in double-quote
- extra comma before WHERE

Also the number of values provided (11) does not match the number of *placeholders* (12) in the SQL statement.

Actually you don't need to update the column `"Case ID"` because it is the searching condition.

Below is the updated SQL statement with correct order and number of provided values:

```py
my_cursor.execute('''\
    UPDATE criminal_records
    SET "Criminal Name" = ?,
        "Case Number" = ?,
        "Date of crime" = ?,
        "Crime Type" = ?,
        "Description" = ?,
        "Block" = ?,
        "Location" = ?,
        "Arrest Date" = ?,
        "Age" = ?,
        "Gender" = ?
    WHERE "Case ID" = ?''',
    (
        self.var_name.get(),
        self.var_case_number.get(),
        self.var_date_of_crime.get(),
        self.var_crime_type.get(),
        self.var_description.get(),
        self.var_block.get(),
        self.var_location.get(),
        self.var_arrest_date.get(),
        self.var_age.get(),
        self.var_gender.get(),
        self.var_case_id.get(),
    )
)
```